# Фильтр вложенной коллекции с помощью Criteria API, Hibernate, Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria

У меня есть два класса описывающие сущности - родительскую (Company) и дочернюю (Developer).
В родительской сущности дочерние представлены коллекцией. При использовании Criteria API я пытаюсь
получить объект Company с отфильтрованными (Predicate) дочерними объектами в коллекции. Hibernate возвращает объект
Company c коллекцией объектов Developer (по указанному фильтру), но потом все равно подгружает остальные дочерние элементы в коллекцию.
Я так понимаю, это связно с контекстом персистентности и, вероятно, мне надо дальше вручную отфильтровывать коллекцию, чтобы отдать представлению.
Или это костыль? Существует ли какой-то способ получить объект родительской сущности с "временно выкинутыми" дочерними, чтобы не костылить и не писать
лишнего кода? Я изучаю Spring всего 2 недели... Прошу помощи.

```
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Company> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Company.class);
        Root<Company> rootCompany = criteriaQuery.from(Company.class);
        Join<Company, Developer> join = rootCompany.join("developers");
        criteriaQuery.select(rootCompany);
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("name"), "name"));
        TypedQuery<Company> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        List<Company> companies = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: [Parameterized Filtering](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping#parameterized-filtering-with-filter)?

Comment: Через запрос. Пример - https://dev.to/golovpavel/make-a-request-with-sub-condition-for-child-list-via-spring-data-jpa-4inn

Comment: Кратко и абстрактно опишите бизнес-задачу.
Если вам требуется получить и обработать  именно коллекцию Developer, так может ну ее, Company. А запрашивать именно Developer и там уже добавлять фильтр, что они принадлежат компании?

Comment: Спасибо, Alexandr! Возможно сделать через @Filter.